# Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml, parsing, utf

i'm trying to convert `xml` to html using `xslt`. Am using `java.xml.transform` to do this in java.
it was working fine until i bumped into some `xml`. it said the following error.

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog. 
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: 
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: 
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: 
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

so i made sure there is no character before the xml declaration. i even took care of BOM using the solution 
http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10324562#10324562

STILL no luck and it happens only for one xml. i even opened the xml in editor and saved it in a file with `utf-8` encoding. this is driving me crazy. any idea?

UPDATE: You get this error when you have given the wrong path for the `xsl` file and a file not found exception happens.
(this was my case. it might help somebody. thanks for your responses)

Comment: show the XML file (upload somewhere)

Comment: It might help to know something about the xml file. Can you paste it (or some of it)?

Comment: @Bozho and @Marcelo uploaded the file at http://www.2shared.com/document/tbf2IXUy/test2.html

Comment: I think it would be better if the XML (or maybe just the relevant part of it) is in the question - this way the question can be taken as a whole, without having to leave the page.

Comment: Answers by both Noel & Jesper were helpful. Help me choose the right answer guys. I cant decide as the prob wasn't in xml or xsl but xsl file path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138696/org-xml-sax-saxparseexception-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog)

Answer (score 6):

This kind of thing can happen if you have an UTF-8 file with a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), and if you use an XML parser that isn't aware of it. Save the XML file as UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue for me. Calling the BOM "content"... Thanks, error message!

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a header in your file? Something like:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

That should be at the start of the first line. Unfortunately I can't see your XML file as that URL is blocked from where I am.