# Blogger template "XML error message" ]

Tags: xml, templates, blogger

Need help with HTML for blogger template--it says "Your template could not be parsed as it is not well-formed. Please make sure all XML elements are closed properly. XML error message: Content is not allowed in prolog"

I changed some of the problems they asked me to fix such as how in "line 231 column 2 needs ending html tag" or things like this, but right now I don't know what they're asking and I haven't got that much background knowledge in html. D:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Love in winter.</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeNavigation(id)
{document.getElementById('main').innerHTML=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
body{
background: url(http://i413.photobucket.com/albums/pp217/cottonlovescandy/bgbg-1.gif);
font-size: 11px;
color: #777777;
line-height: 150%;
font-family: arial;
font-weight: normal;
cursor:url("http://lovelycore.com/hand.ani");}

body, td, th{
color: #777777;
font-size: 11px;
line-height: 15px;
font-family: arial;}

strong {color: #ED8F99;}
i {color: #ffafaf;}
s {color: #ffafaf;}
b {font-family: "arial", sans-serif; color: #ffafaf;}
u {color: #6C6461; border-bottom: 1px solid #B3DE69; text-decoration: none;}

A:link
{text-decoration: none; color: #777777; cursor: url("http://digilander.libero.it/loredanatemplate/cursori/145.ani");}
A:visited
{text-decoration: none; color: #777777; cursor: url("http://digilander.libero.it/loredanatemplate/cursori/145.ani");}
A:active
{text-decoration: none; color: #777777; cursor: url("http://digilander.libero.it/loredanatemplate/cursori/145.ani");}
A:hover
{text-decoration: none; color: #ffafaf; cursor: url("http://digilander.libero.it/loredanatemplate/cursori/145.ani");}

select, input, textarea{
padding: 4px;
font-size: 11px;
color: #C0B09A;
font-family: verdana;
border: 1px solid #FFDBFF;
background-color: #FFF7FF;}

blockquote{
padding: 5px;
color: #666666;
font: 11px arial;
letter-spacing: 1px;
border: 1px solid #ffafaf;
}

.box{
text-align: justify;
background-color: #1E1E1E;}

.heading{
color: #FFAFAF;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 19px;
letter-spacing: -1pt;
font-family: century gothic;}

.head4{
padding: 6px;
color: #996633;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 19px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: none;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-family: century gothic;}

.blogger-labels{
color: #70C3B0;
font: 8pt georgia;
text-transform: lowercase;}

.image{
padding: 5px;
background: #F4F7EC;
border: 1px solid #E8E6DA;}

.date{
font: 7pt arial;
color: #808080;
text-align: right;
line-height: 11pt;
margin-right: 10px;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: #FBFBFB;
border-top: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;}

.title{
padding: 5px;
font-size: 18pt;
color: #ffafaf;
text-align: right;
font-family: calibri;
font-weight: none;
letter-spacing: -2px;
text-transform: lowercase;
}

#entry {text-align: justify;}
#footer{text-align: center; border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;}

::-moz-selection {color: #999999; background: #EEEEEE;}

.h1{
font-size: 9pt;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: "Georgia", serif;
border-bottom: 1px solid #FDE8D7;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
background-color: #FFADAD;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 0 5px;
line-height: 190%;}

.h2{
font-size: 15pt;
text-align: right;
color: #A5A5A5;
line-height: 100%;
font-weight: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #E2E2E2;}

.border{
border-right : 1px solid #DCDCDC;
padding : 0px 5px 20px 0px; }

#navigation {
  height:2.7em;
  line-height:2.7em;
background-color:#FFADAD;
}

#navigation ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#navigation li {
border-color:white;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  border-top:none;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

#navigation li a {
color:white;
  display:block;
  padding:0 18px;
  font-size:0.8em;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:1px;
}

#navigation a:hover
  {background-color:#ffbbbb}

* html #navigation a {width:1%;} 

#navigation form {
  border-color:white;
  background:#FEC42D url(http://img295.imageshack.us/img295/7783/blogyblixcornerbottomriwa5.gif) bottom right no-repeat;
  float:right;
  height:100%;
  width:189px;
  padding:0 15px;
  border-left:1px solid;
  line-height:0;
}

#navigation form fieldset {
  margin-top:7px;
  border:0 solid; 
}
* html #navigation form fieldset {margin-top:7px;}

#navigation #s {
border-color:#FFF9EA;
  height:1.5em;
  width:140px;
  margin:0 5px 0 0;
  padding:0;
  border:1px solid;
  font-size:0.8em;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#navigation #searchbutton {
  color:white;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  height:2em;
  width:auto;
  padding:0 1px;
  border:1px solid;
  font-size:9px;
  letter-spacing:1px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}


</style>

<link rel="me" href="http://www.blogger.com/profile/03121445148229752476" />
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.blogger.com/openid-server.g" />
<!-- --><style type="text/css">@import url(http://www.blogger.com/static/v1/v-css/navbar/697174003-classic.css);
div.b-mobile {display:none;}
</style>
</head>

<noembed>
<body><script type="text/javascript">function setAttributeOnload(object, attribute, val) {if(window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener("load",function(){ object[attribute] = val; }, false);} else 
</script></body></noembed> </html>



<div style="position: absolute;  left: 135px; top: 12px;">
<table width="450" border="0" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr><td colspan="2"><img src="http://i413.photobucket.com/albums/pp217/cottonlovescandy/emolovee.gif">
<div id='navigation'>
  <ul>
 <center><li class='selected'><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
 <li><a href='http://oreocheezecake.blogspot.com'>designer</a></li>
 <li><a href='msnim:add?contact=yourmailhere@hotmail.com'>MSN</a></li>
 <li><a href='http://blogskins.com/me/_oreos_'>Blogskins</a></li>
 <li><a href='http://www.facebook.com/'>Facebook</a></li>
 </center>
  </ul></div></td></tr>

<tr valign="top">
<td width="230">
<div class="border">
<div class="h1">Music</div>
<center>
Your playlist here.
</center><br>

<div class="h1">Disclaimer</div>
<center>여기에서 환영 ! <br>Welcome to <font color=#ffafaf>yoururlhere.blogspot.com</font>!<br>
This site is best viewed in <font color=#ffafaf>Internet Explorer</font>. And please forebear from <font color=#ffafaf>copying</font> or <font color=#ffafaf>ripping</font> anything from here that does not belong to you. 
Thank you for coming by.<br><br>
<center><img src="http://i495.photobucket.com/albums/rr312/angelicreations/graphics/sitestats/screenstats2_pink.gif" border="0" ><br> </center>
</center>
<br>

<div class="h1">Tagboard</div>
Your tagboard.
<br>



<div class="h1">Webmistress</div>
Your profile.<br><br>

<br></center>

<div class="h1">Affilates</div>
<center>
Your Link here.
<br>

<div class="h1">Blog Archives</div>
  <div align="left"><BloggerPreviousItems> <br>
♥<a class="link" href="<$BlogItemPermalinkURL$>"> <$BlogPreviousItemTitle$></a>
</BloggerPreviousItems></div><br>

<center><form name="htmlp1" ACTION=URI>
    <select name="menu" onchange="jump(this.form)"
    style="font-family:Tahoma; font-align:center;"
    style="color:#ffafaf;"
    style="font-size:8pt;"
    style="background: url(http://dl4.glitter-graphics.net/pub/678/678644gz6asg8ibk.png); ">
    <option value="#">Click ♥</option><BloggerArchives>
    <option value="<$BlogArchiveURL$>"> ♥ <$MTArchiveTitle$></option></BloggerArchives>
    </select>
    </form></center>
<br>
<div class="h1">Thank You</div>
<center>Please do not remove credits. </center>
<center><a href="http://piggybacked.blogspot.com/" target="_blank"><img src="http://i413.photobucket.com/albums/pp217/cottonlovescandy/2button.gif" border="0"></a><br>
This blogskin is proudly designed by <b><a href="http://piggybacked.blogspot.com">Fan</a><a href="http://www.blogskins.com/me/_oreos_">ny.</a>♥</b><br>
</center><img src="http://i26.tinypic.com/2vb0y0y.gif"> <a href="http://www.blogskins.com/me/piinkifiedd">Basecodes 1</a> l Piinklifiedd<br>
<img src="http://i26.tinypic.com/2vb0y0y.gif"> <a href="http://www.blogskins.com/me/indreamsmaybe">Basecodes 2</a> l InDreamsMaybe<br>
<img src="http://i26.tinypic.com/2vb0y0y.gif"> <a href="http://www.blogskins.com/me/mssockpuppet">codes 1</a> l Ms.SockPuppet<br>
<img src="http://i26.tinypic.com/2vb0y0y.gif"> <a href="http://www.little-miss-wendy.com/">codes 2</a> l Little-Miss-Wendy<br>
<img src="http://i26.tinypic.com/2vb0y0y.gif"> <a href="http://cyworld.com/">Materials 1</a> l cyworld<br>
<img src="http://i26.tinypic.com/2vb0y0y.gif"> <a href="http://angelicreations.co.nr/">Materials 2</a> l Angelicreations<br>


<p></p></td>
</div>
<td width="600" id="main">
<MTEntries lastn="7">
<div class="title"><font style="font-family: trebuchet ms; color: #A2C5D6; font-size: 20pt;"></font> <$BlogItemTitle$></div>
<div class="date"><MTDateHeader><$MTEntryDate format="%B %e, %Y"$></MTDateHeader> | <$MTEntryDate format="%I:%M:%S %p"$> </div><br>
<div align="left"><$MTEntryBody$></div><br>
</MTEntries><br>

</div><br /></div></td></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr></table></div></body>


 <script language=JavaScript>
                <!--

                //Disable right click script III- By Renigade (renigade@mediaone.net)
                //For full source code, visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com

                var message="";
                ///////////////////////////////////
                function clickIE() {if (document.all) {(message);return false;}}
                function clickNS(e) {if 
                (document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) {
                if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {(message);return false;}}}
                if (document.layers) 
                {document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);document.onmousedown=clickNS;}
                else{document.onmouseup=clickNS;document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;}

                document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")
                // --> 
                </script></html>
```

Please help D: thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This validation error is a bit tricky. "Content is not allowed in prolog" usually means that there is an illegal byte in the beginning of the file. This is sometimes caused by editing the file in an editor and not saving it properly as UTF-8 without byte order marking. Have a look at this: [Content is not allowed in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395560/content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog)

I had a check of your blogger template using an XML validator, and there are quite a number of errors still in the file. I would go and check the file first using http://validator.w3.org/, and then make sure that the xml is valid utf-8. I suspect it is not since there are ♥ characters in there that don't look right.

Answer (score 0):

you are placing the body and the HTML tag in the wrong places..

from line 228 to 231:

```
<noembed>
<body><script type="text/javascript">function setAttributeOnload(object, attribute, val) {if(window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener("load",function(){ object[attribute] = val; }, false);} else 
</script></body></noembed> </html>
```

should be:

```
<body><noembed><script type="text/javascript">function setAttributeOnload(object, attribute, val) {if(window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener("load",function(){ object[attribute] = val; }, false);} else 
</script></noembed>
```

line 316:

```
</div><br /></div></td></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr></table></div></body>
```

remove `</body>`

line 337:

```
       </script></html>
```

replace with:

```
       </script></body></html>
```

Please oh please, make sure that your tags are properly placed! By simply putting it in an IDE, you can see that the HTML tags are not properly closed or structured.

Answer (score 0):

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 8; columnNumber: 43; The reference to entity "l" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?